# Fetching result isn't working after prepared statement

Tags: php

I'm struggling to write this myself so I will say what I know I need to do and what I have already.

Based on two $_GET[] variables I need to query a database. The values provide me with the table name and the name of the location. From this location field name, I need to extrapolate the whole row.

So, I query the database with this data, however when I try and fetch and print it nothing happens. I need the whole row's data (in an array?).

**I understand my code is ugly**. And probably vulnerable to MySQL injection, but I would rather get my PHP right in terms of getting the row into an array before I worry about that.

Rough code I have so far:

```
$company = strtolower($_GET['company'] . '_a_in_m2f');
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $company);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $company ." WHERE `name` = '?'");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $stop);

$stop = $_GET['stop'];

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($therow);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s \n", $therow);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You don't quote the variable you are going to bind (as mentioned before...);
2. You don't escape the table name, instead you should check it against a white-list and quote it in backticks if necessary;
3. You don't bind the results to an array but to individual variables. You would be better of just fetching rows from the result using [`fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Where specifically in the code should I use mysqli_fetch_row? In the while loop or? (Still learning mysqli, so different to mysql (which I miss a lot :P)).

Comment: @jskidd3 Yes, just check example #1 from the manual page I linked to, or here (more complete): http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the placeholder:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $company ." WHERE `name` = ?");
                                                                       ^--no quotes
```

The whole point of placeholders/named parameters in prepared statements is to remove the need for you to do such things yourself.

Internally, the DB library would be doing the equivalent of:

```
$safe = "'" . escape($nasty_unsafe_data) . "'"
```

so the final query would end up looking like

```
... WHERE `name` = ''$safe''
```

(not really, this is just to illustrate the process).

Comment: Thanks but printf still echos no data. :(

Comment: @jskidd3, May be that is because it didn't find any rows.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind the `?` with quotes. Remove quotes from `'?'` to simply `?`

Comment: @MarcB, Oh yeah, saw it :)

Comment: That doesn't matter though right? The variable only has to be instantiated before the statement is executed? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @jskidd3, Yes it does not matter. I just didn't saw it. My bad.

Comment: @jskidd3, If the query should return a row, can you try `$stmt->bind_param(1, $stop);`?